# Script to read and compare excel data

Tags: excel, loops, batch-file, comparison

I'm fairly new to writing scripts but I've been given a task at work that I need to write a script for. Here's the list of things I need to do .

I need some sort of script that will:

1. Take the two folders as inputs
2. Generate a list of all the files in one of them.
3. For each file:

   - Read in the data from columns D-G
   - Find the matching file in the other folder and read in the same data
   - Compare each cell and verify that the two files match exactly
   - If they don’t match, report what data doesn’t match

Here is what I've done so far, I know its not great. For one thing, I've only really gotten to step one. If someone only wants to address step one for now thats fine. If I can get that working, I can work on figuring out steps 2-3.

```
@echo off

rem This is to make sure the folders are on the local machine
rmdir c:\directory1 /s /q
mkdir c:\directory1
xcopy "\\SERVER\Path\to\the\folders\and\files" c:\directory1

cd c:\directory1

for /D /r %%a in ("*") do (
    for %%i in ('forfiles /p "%%a" /m *.xlsx /c "cmd /c echo @fname"') do echo %%~nxi
    )
pause
```

I'm very uncertain about the loop. I'm trying to generate the list of all files in directory1. I'm very shaking with loops in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use vba in excel to do the entire thing and you can also build  GUI or Form to make it clear what files are being compared and differences found

Comment: I have no experience writing VBA scripts

Comment: Well I could help you if you like - stevenmartin99@gmail.com